# Behavior of default `equals` changes when member/setter is added?

Tags: java, equals

I have a question about the Java "equals" method.

I created a class called Person:

```
public class Person {

}
```

And I am comparing two references to Person like this.

```
Person p1 = new Person();
Person p2 = new Person();
System.out.println(p1.equals(p2));     //returns false
```

If I add any instance variable and setter method to set the instance variable, then the "equals" method returns true.

Can anybody explain this behavior?

Comment: Can you post your code? The additions of methods or fields should not affect the equals method, something else must be going on.

Comment: Adding a setter method and instance variable will not make the Object equal. You must be making other changes as well. Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that demonatrates this behaviour.

Comment: (See the answer from Dev and my comment on it.)

Answer (score 14):

If you do not override Object.equals(Object) then the default implementation uses the objects identity for comparison. (i.e. equals only returns true if the objects are the same object in memory).

Relevant JavaDoc: [Object.equals](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

Excerpt:

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

```
Object a = new Object();
Object b = new Object();
System.out.println(a.equals(b)); // Prints 'false'
b = a;
System.out.println(a.equals(b)); // Prints 'true'
```

As I mentioned in one of my comments the additions of methods or fields should not affect the default implementation of equals method, something else must be going on.

Comment: +1 To poster: This answer is correct. The behavior that is being observed *will not deviate from this unless `equals` is overridden*. Perhaps there is something else amiss in the "odd case" such as `p2 = p1; p1.equals(p2)`, which should always be true for a non-null `p1` (which does not incorrectly override `equals`).

Comment: This is true, but it doesn’t quite answer the OP’s question. Why does merely adding a field and a setter change the behavior of equals()?

Comment: @Lawrence I added a comment that asks for a code example, because "merely adding a field and a setter" does not change the behavior of equals. Something else is going on.

Comment: @pst @Dev That's what I thought; the whole thing seemed pretty fishy. I guess I didn't read @pst's comment properly. :)

Answer (score -2):

`p1` and `p2` are two different references, that's why. It will return `false` unless you have your own `equals` method. It doesn't matter if you have instance variable or not.

Comment: You might want to elaborate on this answer. As it stands, it is unclear how it relates to the original question.